# get php button value and use on different page

Tags: php, mysql

Objective: My main.php displays the courses in my class. Based on which one I click, It should show me all the projects for that specific course ( either a dropdown or for now I'm displaying them in displayProjects.php) So i need to get the id of the clicked php button, write a query to search that name with it's corresponding class_id in the student table, in order to get the project names. DO I need some sort of Ajax call to get the php onclick button value or maybe a session var to display in my displayprojects.php page?

**Main.php**

```
result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `course_code`FROM `class`");
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo  "<a href='displayProjects.php'> <input type='submit' id='project'  class='btn btn-primary'   style='display:block; width:10%; margin-bottom:10px;' value=". $row['course_code'] . ">";
}
echo "<tr><td><a href='CreateNewClass.php'><button type='button'> Create a New Class </button></a></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

**displayProjects.php**

Need help modifying this query to get projects based on class_id

```
$projectQuery=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT project_name from Student S ");
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projectQuery)) { 
    echo "<a href='displayGroups.php'> <input type='button'  id='project'  class='btn btn-primary'   style='display:block; width:10%; margin-bottom:10px;' value=". $row['project_name'] . ">";
}
echo "</table>";
```

class table . 
[image: class table] .

student table
[image: student table]

Comment: Your `<input>` "inside" an `<a href>` is of no use. (You're also missing a closing `</a>`) You need to add a `<form>` element around your input to get the value of that input element in your PHP - or use a GET parameter on your link, i.e. `<a href='displayProjects.php?code=" . $row['course_code'] . "'>` Also, `<button>` inside `<a></a>` is not valid, remove the button and style your `<a>` to look like a button

Comment: Neither `<a>`, `<button>`, nor `<form>` can be child elements of a `<table>` either. You need to learn basic HTML.

Comment: @kerbholz ok so I can fix all that but can you explain my original problem, to get the value of the button I click and use it in the next page? is that the only way in order to search that button value in the DB to display projects based on it?

Comment: As I wrote, you can use something like `<a href='displayProjects.php?code=" . $row['course_code'] . "'>Get course</a>` and access `$_GET['code']` in your `displayProjects.php` to access that value.